# Error en peticion Get a api Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, gson

Tengo el siguiente codigo para consumir datos desde la api pero me lanza el error

> Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY

La url de mi api tiene este formato "https://xxxxx.mx/myapi/api/datos/03998"

Este es el formato JSON devuelto

```
[
  {
    id: 165,
    codigo: "03998",
    nombre: "MA. DEL SOCORRO",
    ubicacion: "LEON",
    telefono: "9999999999",
    liberacion: "S",
    estatus: "1"
  },
  {
    id: 166,
    codigo: "03998",
    nombre: "LUIS OLIVAS",
    ubicacion: "JALISCO",
    telefono: "9999999999",
    liberacion: "S",
    estatus: "1"
  }
]
```

Modelo

```
data class DataList(val dataList: ArrayList<Data>)

data class Data ( val id:Int,
                       val codigo:String,
                       val nombre:String,
                       val ubicacion:String,
                       val telefono:String,
                       val liberacion:String,
                       val estatus:String)
```

Interfaz

```
interface IApiService {
@GET("datos/")
suspend fun getData(@Query("codigo") query : String): DataList
}
```

RetroInstance

```
class RetroInstance {
    companion object{
        val BaseUrl="https://xxxxx.mx/myapi/api/"

        fun getRetroInstance(): Retrofit {
            return Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BaseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es que la estructura del JSON no coincide con la de tu modelo.

Hay dos soluciones posibles:

1. Modificar el JSON para que coincida con la estructura de `DataList`. Es decir convertirlo en un objeto que contenga un array de objetos

   ```
   {
     dataList: [
       {...},
       {...}
     ]
   }
   ```
2. Cambiar el return type del el método `getData` por algo que coincida con la estructura del JSON (un array de objetos)

   ```
   @GET("datos/")
   suspend fun getData(@Query("codigo") query : String): List<Data>
   ```